# ComponentDidMount Updates State, but doesnt seem to re-render component

Tags: reactjs

The problem I face is that it doesn't seem that componentDidMount is re-rendering my component, even though it is updating the state. Lot of code coming up, but it gives context to the issue I'm having. If I need to, I can upload screenshots of what is happening.

Here's the constructor:

```
export class Upload extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, UploadTaggingOptions> {

constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        photographer: [
            { id: null, value: '', label: '' },
        ],
    };  
}
```

Here's component did mount:

```
componentDidMount {
    //Fetch request for photographers from the db
    fetch("http://localhost:49775/api/photographers")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((result) => {
            var photographerData = this.state!.photographer;
            var y = 0;
            //Remove the empty object first and foremost. The list should now be totally empty
            photographerData.shift();
            //The loop to add the galleries to the galleryData array
            for (var i in result) {
                var id = result[i].id;
                var value = result[i].firstname + ' ' + result[i].lastname;
                var label = value;
                var photographer = { "id": id, "value": value, "label": label };
                photographerData.push(photographer);
                y++;
            }


            this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                photographer: photographerData
            });

        },
            (error) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    error
                });
                alert("Error loading options for the photographers. Refresh the page. If the error persists, please contact your administrator");
        }
    )
```

And finally Render:

```
 public render() {

    return <div>

        <div className="photographers"> 
            <p><b>Photographer:</b></p>
            <DropDown options={this.state!.photographer} />
        </div>
}
```

Just for clarity's sake, there are more components on the screen (hence the extra div for the dropdown component).

I'm not sure why, but the dropdown renders with the blank options I intitialize in the constructor, componentdidupdate does the fetch request AND updates the state to the data that was fetched, but I have to click the blank value in order to load those data values into the dropdown. It is almost like it re-renders after I change the selected value instead of on state change.

I've tried moving those requests into the constructor, but have the same problem. Perhaps

EDIT: Here's the code for the Dropdown component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';


const DropDown = (props: any) => {
    return (
        <div className="dropdown">
            <Select
                closeOnSelect={!(props.stayOpen)}
                disabled={props.disabled}
                options={props.options}
                placeholder="Select an option..."
                removeSelected={props.removeSelected}
                simpleValue
                value={props.selectedPhotographer}
                searchable={true}
                multi={true}
            />
        </div>
    )
}

export default DropDown;
```

Comment: is your API call working fine? did you check that?

Comment: Yeah. As far as I'm aware it is working as expected. It functions, there just seems to be a delay as to when the data is getting loaded.

Comment: can you post the code of DropDown component?

Comment: Of course. I'll update the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From react official [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state):

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.

But in your code you are mutating it, albeit via an assignment to another variable:

```
var photographerData = this.state!.photographer;
// this DOES mutate the original array.
photographerData.shift();
```

This can mess with Reacts batching update strategy and can cause delays.

If you do not need the data from original state, you can just do:

```
var photographerData = [];
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  console.log('Testing');
  let testArr1 = [1, 2, 3]
  console.log('TestArr1 length before shift: ' + testArr1.length);
  let testArr2 = testArr1;
  testArr2.shift();
  console.log('TestArr1 length after shift: ' + testArr1.length);

}
```

Comment: Can't seem to get TypeScript to match types. The photographer is defined as [{id:any, value: string, label: string}], but I can't seem to figure out how to write photographerData so that it is initially empty. Hence why I set it to the current state.

Comment: never mind. It is how I was defining the type in the interface. Found out that [{object type}] is not the same as {object type}[].

Comment: haven't had any experience with TS yet, so couldn't help there. But it is good to know!. Also, btw, react-select seems to have release v2 recently and I think the author has added inbuilt `async` module, may help simplify your component.

Comment: How so? I'm not too familiar with using the async attributes of react in general, so I dont know how it'll help simplify the component. Do you have any resources that could help explain this?

Comment: Sure... Here is the official example I could find: https://react-select.com/async it also has the "view source" button.

Comment: That's actually pretty interesting. However, I'm not sure how that would simplify the component I'm currently working on. I have to create the initial state and pass those values down into the Dropdown component. Unless you're suggesting that I do the fetch request in the dropdown component and load the data as I need it?

Comment: yup, that is what I am suggesting. As the component can handle promises, it should be able to fetch your data. That way you  don't need to mess with the lifecycle and other such things. I am not using react-select, but I would expect it to manage the "loading" and error states. It might be worth investigating.

Comment: So, instead of initializing the lists of object data in state, I can simply have the dropdown load that information as it needs it?

Comment: Yup. As long as you don't need that data array outside your drop down component, there's really no need for it to be lifted to a parent component. If the drop down library is not able to handle it to your liking, you can lift it back to a parent component and fully control the select component